# A control is already associated with the element - How do I discover the id of the control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, reportviewer

I am developing a web application using asp.net and c#. I am also using sql server reporting services (ssrs), and I present the reports generated by ssrs in my website. Presenting these reports is done by using a built in microsoft control which is called a *report viewer*. The report viewer control uses a lot of ajax calls to update the reports graphs, generated to the end user. I am performing some minor manipulation of the rendered html (and dom), and at that point from some reason I get the following **javascript** error:

```
A control is already associated with the element
```

what I am trying to figure out is, how can I discover what is the origin of the error - meaning what is the id of the control the error is relating to?

**EDIT** 
Thanks to some of the mate's responses down here I am clarifying the question. So many hours of work on the same annoying mini project made me forget that what I am writing about isn't clear to anyone but me.

Thank you

Comment: never understood how we are suppose to help with no code provided...

Comment: Also what is a "report viewer control"?

Comment: We need a **lot** more context (and some code) to be helpful here. I'm guessing from your other questions you're using ASP.Net? If so, I'd *really* recommend adding the relevant tag(s).

Comment: Your question couldn't be more vague. Please elaborate on it.

Comment: @vondip Which program is reporting the error? Your browser, your IDE?

Comment: @vondip What is generating the error in question?  Is this a javascript error?  An ASP.net error?  An error from the report viewer you're using?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

have you try the uniqueid

> button1.UniqueID

This will print the id generated in asp specially if you are working with master pages, it generates its own ids.

IF you do a print of the uniqueID of the property in you javascript you will get the ID generated by aspm and you wont have to worry about the actual id printed in the page.